# problema de diseño de menu despegable en CSS:

Tags: html, css

solicito su ayuda para solucionar el siguiente problema.

estoy replicando en html y css este menu despegable como se ve en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la siguinete imagen a continuacion aqui esta mi replica en html y css.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver mi diseño del menu despegable esta mal. He intentado solucionarlo reducienmdo el with, height, font size, y demas pero aun asi no sale como la pagina original. lespido su ayuda para que mi replica del menu despegable quede igual que el menu despegable original. muchas gracias por su atencion.

aqui esta el link de la pagina original.

https://vivelaconco.com/gdl/ca.html

aqui estan los codigos en html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3.02 ejercicio desde 0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="nav-bar">

        <div class="barra">

            <div id="logotipo-1">
                <span class="logo-1">
                    <img src="image/con-co.png" alt="concomics">
                </span>
                <h3>vive la conco</h3>
            </div>

            <nav id="menu-lista"> <!-- ESTO MUEVE EL MENU DE IZQ. A DER. -->

                <ul id="lista-2">
                    <li><a href="#">INVITADOS. </a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">CONCURSOS. </a>
                        <ul class="menu-vertical">
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">ALLEY'S. </a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">GAMING. </a>
                        <ul class="menu-vertical">
                            <li><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">INFO GENERAL. </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="comprar-tickets">
                <div id="comprar">
                    <h3>CONTENIDO</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

aqui esta los codigos en CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}


body {
    background-image: url(image/speakersbg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

#nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 241px;
    background: url("image/banner-inner2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;

    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 162px;
}

#logotipo-1 {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 300ms;
}

#logotipo-1 img {
    width: 70px;
    height: 52px;
}

#logotipo-1 h3 {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(50, 51, 51, .8);
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}


#menu-lista {
    max-width: 440px;
    float: right;
    background: transparent;
    padding-right: 255px;
    padding-top: 46px;
}

#lista-2 {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

#lista-2 li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;

    font-size: 13px;

    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -0.3px;

    padding: 28px 20px;
}

.menu-vertical {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    width: 190px;
    height: 170px;
}

#lista-2 li:hover .menu-vertical {
    display: block;
}

.menu-vertical {
    background-color: rgb(136, 60, 136);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-vertical li {
    height: 35px;

}

.menu-vertical .fila-vertical {
    height: 35px;
    width: 190px;
   
}


.menu-vertical li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu-vertical li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(61, 108, 207);
    width: 100px;
    height: 5px;
}

#comprar-tickets {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: -660px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 300ms;
}


#comprar-tickets #comprar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ec398b;

}

#comprar-tickets h3 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    line-height: 51px;

}

#comprar-tickets #comprar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ec398b;
    transition: all 400ms;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar:hover {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(image/speakersbg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
#nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 241px;
    background: url("image/banner-inner2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 162px;
}
#logotipo-1 {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
#logotipo-1 img {
    width: 70px;
    height: 52px;
}
#logotipo-1 h3 {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(50, 51, 51, .8);
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}
#menu-lista {
    max-width: 440px;
    float: right;
    background: transparent;
    padding-right: 255px;
    padding-top: 46px;
}
#lista-2 {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
#lista-2 li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -0.3px;
    padding: 28px 20px;
}
.menu-vertical {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    width: 190px;
    height: 170px;
}
#lista-2 li:hover .menu-vertical {
    display: block;
}
.menu-vertical {
    background-color: rgb(136, 60, 136);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.menu-vertical li {
    height: 35px;
}
.menu-vertical .fila-vertical {
    height: 35px;
    width: 190px;
}
.menu-vertical li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu-vertical li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(61, 108, 207);
    width: 100px;
    height: 5px;
}
#comprar-tickets {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: -660px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
#comprar-tickets #comprar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ec398b;

}
#comprar-tickets h3 {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    line-height: 51px;
}
#comprar-tickets #comprar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ec398b;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
#comprar-tickets #comprar:hover {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3.02 ejercicio desde 0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="nav-bar">

        <div class="barra">

            <div id="logotipo-1">
                <span class="logo-1">
                    <img src="image/con-co.png" alt="concomics">
                </span>
                <h3>vive la conco</h3>
            </div>

            <nav id="menu-lista"> <!-- ESTO MUEVE EL MENU DE IZQ. A DER. -->

                <ul id="lista-2">
                    <li><a href="#">INVITADOS. </a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">CONCURSOS. </a>
                        <ul class="menu-vertical">
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
                            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">ALLEY'S. </a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">GAMING. </a>
                        <ul class="menu-vertical">
                            <li><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">INFO GENERAL. </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="comprar-tickets">
                <div id="comprar">
                    <h3>CONTENIDO</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tener un resultado similar las listas desplegables de la página web, el contenedor del desplegable podría tener lo siguiente:

```
.menu-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  width: 190px;
  height: 170px;
  /* agrego estas 4 propiedades */
  background: rgba(85,75,185,.98);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 16px 8px;
}
```

Solamente remuevo los bordes redondeados y coloco un espaciado por dentro del contenedor. El color lo puedes encontrar fácilmente con [**color picker**](https://imagecolorpicker.com/), o yendo a las propiedades CSS (al inspeccionar elemento) de la página web.

---

Ahora, en cada lista, notamos que lleva una opacidad, y al hacer `:hover`, la opacidad vuelve a su estado normal, haciéndose notar más claro los textos. También, las listas se mueven un poco a la izquierda, esto lo podemos lograr colocando un `margin-left` de `5px` al hacer `:hover`, y por último, el color de fondo es blanco con un poco de transparencia. EL código de las listas sería el siguiente:

```
.menu-vertical li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: .6;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  padding: 10px !important;
  transition: .3s ease all;
}

.menu-vertical li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Y tendrías un resultado *casi* similar.

---

### Ejemplo:

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


body {
  background-image: url(image/speakersbg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 241px;
  /*background: url("image/banner-inner2.jpg");*/
  background-color: #1074c0;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "BebasNeue";
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 162px;
}

#logotipo-1 {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

#logotipo-1 img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 52px;
}

#logotipo-1 h3 {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(50, 51, 51, .8);
  line-height: 2.6rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#menu-lista {
  max-width: 440px;
  float: right;
  background: transparent;
  padding-right: 255px;
  padding-top: 46px;
}

#lista-2 {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#lista-2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Oswald, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  padding: 28px 20px;
}

#lista-2 li:hover .menu-vertical {
  display: block;
}

.menu-vertical {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  width: 190px;
  height: 170px;
  background: rgba(85,75,185,.98);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 16px 8px;
}

.menu-vertical li {
  height: 35px;
}

.menu-vertical .fila-vertical {
  height: 35px;
  width: 190px;
}

.menu-vertical li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: .6;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  padding: 10px !important;
  transition: .3s ease all;
}

.menu-vertical li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#comprar-tickets {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: -660px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ec398b;
}

#comprar-tickets h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 51px;

}

#comprar-tickets #comprar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ec398b;
  transition: all 400ms;
}

#comprar-tickets #comprar:hover {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
  <div class="barra">
    <div id="logotipo-1">
      <!--
      <span class="logo-1">
        <img src="image/con-co.png" alt="concomics">
      </span>
      <h3>vive la conco</h3>
      -->
    </div>
    <nav id="menu-lista">
      <ul id="lista-2">
        <li><a href="#">INVITADOS. </a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">CONCURSOS. </a>
          <ul class="menu-vertical">
            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
            <li class="fila-vertical"><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ALLEY'S. </a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">GAMING. </a>
          <ul class="menu-vertical">
            <li><a href="#">PASARELA COSPLAY. </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY PERFORMANCE. </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">COSPLAY INFANTIL. </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DANCE GROUP. </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">INFO GENERAL. </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="comprar-tickets">
      <div id="comprar">
        <h3>CONTENIDO</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: amigo Cris223511.dev muchas gracias por tu ayuda. eso del pìcker si se como usarlo. el problema es el diseño de los elementos a  del menu despegable. me ayudaste mucho al solucionar este problema. muchas gracias.